# Routing all ips under a domain 000.000.x.x through vpn on linux

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, network-protocols, router

I've succesfully run the command below to just add one computer on the network and have no problems connecting to it while the rest of my traffic goes unencrypted through my local connection.

```
sudo route add 000.000.123.123 gw 000.000.202.253 dev tun0
```

If I want to do something like the command below where I want to add everything under the domain 128.250.x.x to be routed to the gw. What is the command to do this? Do I need to change the netmask from 255.255.255.255 to something else?

```
sudo route add 000.000.*.* gw 000.000.202.253 dev tun0
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to just write

```
sudo route add -net 128.250.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 000.000.202.253 dev tun0
```

Comment: I had actually tried that but gave me invalid error. I had not had the -net in the command. Awesome that works great.